# UIScrollView with multiple uiview using as tab bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, tabs, uiscrollview, storyboard

```
viewController
 -->BGScrollview - for Vertical scroll
   -->uiview(tab1) - height 500
   -->uiview(tab2) - height 800
   -->uiview(tab3) - height 1000
   -->uiview(tab4) - height 10
```

this is my design with storyboard autolayout

Here my sample design
[image]

sample code

```
-(void)hideAndShowViewWhenNavigationTabTapped:(NSInteger)selectedControllerTag{
[bgScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];

tab1View.hidden = ((selectedControllerTag == 0)? NO:YES);
tab2View.hidden = ((selectedControllerTag == 1)? NO:YES);
tab1HeightConstraint.constant = ((selectedControllerTag == 0)? 500:0);
tab2HeightConstraint.constant = ((selectedControllerTag == 1)? 800:0);}
```

Someone may suggest why not `UITabbar`. My design doesn't in bottom that's why.

Here my question is: if tab 1 is selected and I need to hide all other tab as same as other tab too. On iPhone6+ tab1 don't need to scroll because it's height lesser than screen height, but bgscrollview `contentOffset 1000` because of autolayout. If add `NSLayoutConstraint` for all uiview and change height into 0 based on selected tab it's show few constraint issues. How can I overcome this.

Addition: all tab have dynamic height

Found somewhere in web like this: In storyBoard viewController free form height and width add scrollView(tab scrollView) to all other scrollView equal width, add widht `NSLayoutConstraint` for `scrollView` (only one) change width in `viewdidLoad` method with screen width. It's look like a tab view width is equal to screen width

```
 viewController
     -->BGScrollview - for Horizontal scroll (pagination enable)
       -->scrollView(tab1) - for vertical scroll
          -->uiview - height 500
       -->scrollView(tab2) - for vertical scroll
          -->uiview - height 800
       -->scrollView(tab3) - for vertical scroll
          -->uiview - height 1000
       -->scrollView(tab4) - for vertical scroll
          -->uiviewheight 1000
```

Using a `UIScrollView` how to do tab bar design with storyboard autolayout. I happy If any one share project or code or example link to solve my problem.

I think maybe it's have a any simpler way to do. Is any don't understant any of above mention add comment and I will change way of asking thanks.

Comment: Provide what you have done and the screenshot if you could.

Comment: @BharatModi you mean code? or project?

Comment: Provide screenshot what you have done and what you have to do?

Comment: Is that enough? or need more? I don't have old one design and code. Now I am trying new design(2nd one) that too not completed so I don't have enough code to provide. If you want project I will create sample code and send you.

Comment: I have read you question in real quick, what i have understood from it is, you have to create custom TabBar using UIView's, and the container view for the TabBar would be a ScrollView. And that TabBar would be at the top of screen. Is that correct? If not, explain what you have to do in brief.

Comment: Yes exactly you are correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106544/discussion-between-bharat-modi-and-user3589771).

Comment: Do you want your TabBar of Views to be Horizontally scroll?

Comment: Yes that too. But now I am using static count view, I just saw a lib in [gitHub JTCalendar](https://github.com/jonathantribouharet/JTCalendar) they are using only three uiview and replacing content. If I understand that code I need like dynamic data load in 3 uiview.